# What Are the Best WordPress Theme Recommendations for CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, mobile

We are about to deploy Civi CRM in our WordPress website. We are using the Avada Theme from ThemeFusion. I came across a couple of comments saying that with Avada's recent upgrades, this was causing CSS and other issues.

Can I ask this community to weigh in on which themes they recommend for a WordPress & CiviCRM website?

What's important to us?

We would love to have some of the bells & whistles that Avada supplies. For example, we can designate whether any block of content on a page will show across all devices (smartphones. tablets, desktops) or only specific devices. This is especially helpful when we don't want some content to show on mobile and when we do want specific content to show on mobile but not desktop.

Most importantly, the theme needs to work with CiviCRM to make it as mobile-friendly as possible.

Many thanks in advance for any recommendations and advice.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the Divi theme from Elegant themes.  It is fully responsive and mobile friendly and we've had very few issues.  We've had some problems with certain plug-ins but not from the theme itself.

Comment: Would you be willing to share your website's URL so that I can see how Civi looks in the site?

Comment: It does look interesting and £89 is a reasonable cost, but I'd need some confidence it would work well with CiviCRM before paying and there doesn't seem to be a way of testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **not** recommended for use with Civi. We use the Bridge theme from Qode Themes. Before Civi integration we had no problems with the theme. But we have CSS issues after installing CiviCRM.